# From window to opengl coordinate system intuitive explanation

Tags: opengl

I am trying to understand the map from window coordinate axis (origin top-left) to `OpenGL` coordinate axis (origin left-bottom) when using the mouse function. In relevant book this map is described by the two following lines:

```
points[count].x = (float) x / (w/2) - 1.0;
points[count].y = (float) (h-y) / (h/2) - 1.0;
```

I suspect that these two lines depict a scale. Could you please give an intuitive-mathematical explanation of this map?

Comment: The book from Angel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What book are you referring to? The origin in NDC-space is the center of the viewport (**0,0** is the center; **-1,-1** is the bottom-left; **1,1** is the top-right). Any other coordinate space is defined by your projection matrix.

I believe what the book is trying to teach you is that **NDC**<sub>-1,-1</sub> is the bottom-left corner of your viewport and **NDC**<sub>1,1</sub> is the top-right corner.

#### A more complete mapping would include the X and Y location of your viewport:

- NDC<sub>X</sub> = (2.0 * (Screen<sub>X</sub> - Viewport<sub>X</sub>) / Viewport<sub>W</sub>) - 1.0;
- NDC<sub>Y</sub> = (2.0 * (Screen<sub>Y</sub> - Viewport<sub>Y</sub>) / Viewport<sub>H</sub>) - 1.0;

#### [This mapping](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vertex_Transformations) is illustrated below <sub>(the square on the right is the viewport):</sub>

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/23/Viewport_transformation.png]

*You of course have one additional step necessary since the Y-axis runs the opposite direction in your mouse coordinate system. That is why you see the Y-axis flipped in your mapping `h-y`*