# Transformed coordinates returned by transform feedback open gl

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm using transform feedback approach to capture the transformed coordinates vertices after loading them. I'm testing on a simple CUBE with 4 faces (the bottom and top faces are not considered).

Here is my code , and the results i got. You will notice that the coordinates i get back are outside the range of [-1 1]. In many tutorials, they say that they have to be inside this interval.  Can you help me ?

```
// Link statically with GLEW
#define GLEW_STATIC

// Headers
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include<glm/glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include<glm/glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

 #define GLSL(src) "#version 150 core\n" #src

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec3 position;"
    "in vec3 color;"

    "out vec3 Color;"
        "out vec4 outposition;"
    "uniform mat4 model;"
    "uniform mat4 view;"
    "uniform mat4 proj;"

    "void main() {"

    "   Color = color;"

    "   gl_Position = proj * view    * vec4(position, 1.0);"

        "outposition=gl_Position;"
    "}";


const GLchar* fragmentSource =
    "#version 150 core\n"
    "in vec3 Color;"

    "out vec4 outColor;"


    "void main() {"
    "   outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0) ;"
    "}";

int main()
{
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.depthBits = 24;
    settings.stencilBits = 8;

    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close, settings);
glViewport( 0 , 0 , 800,600 );
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
 glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
 glColorMask;
 //glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
 //glFrontFace(GL_CW);// pour lui dire que les polygones faces à la caméra ont des noeuds dans le sens horaire
 //glCullFace(GL_BACK);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    glewInit();

    // Create and compile the vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // Create and compile the fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

   // Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");

   const GLchar* feedbackVaryings[] = { "outposition" };
        glTransformFeedbackVaryings(shaderProgram, 1, feedbackVaryings, GL_INTERLEAVED_ATTRIBS);

    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    // Create Vertex Array Object
    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    // Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);


//cube avec des faces carrees
  GLfloat vertices2[] = {
    //Frontie red

        -1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //bottom left

       1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //bottom right

       1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //top right

      -1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, //top left

        //Rightvert
       //
        1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
        1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

        //Back bleu

        -1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        -1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

         1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

         1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

        //Left jaune

         -1.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         -1.5f, -1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         -1.5f, 1.0f, 1.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
         -1.5f, 1.0f, -1.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
      };    


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices2), vertices2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Specify the layout of the vertex data
    GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

    GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
    glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(3 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

    GLint uniModel = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "model");

    // Set up projection
    glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 9.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
        glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
    );
    GLint uniView = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "view");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniView, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

    glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(45.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);
    GLint uniProj = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "proj");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniProj, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(proj));
       //Create transform feedback buffer
        GLuint tbo;
        glGenBuffers(1, &tbo);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices2), NULL, GL_STATIC_READ);

        // Perform feedback transform
        glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);
        glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, tbo);
        glBeginTransformFeedback(GL_POINTS);
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 48);
        glEndTransformFeedback();
        glDisable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD);

         glFlush();

        // Fetch and print results
        GLfloat feedback[64];
        glGetBufferSubData(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(feedback), feedback);
int k=0;
        for(int i=0;i<64;i++)
        {            
            cout<<feedback[i]<<" ";
            k++;
            if(k==4){cout<<endl; k=0;}
        }

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event windowEvent;
        while (window.pollEvent(windowEvent))
        {
            switch (windowEvent.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Clear the screen to black
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT    | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Calculate transformation
        glm::mat4 model;
        model = glm::rotate(model,/*(GLfloat)clock() / (GLfloat)CLOCKS_PER_SEC*/ 0.0f,glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniModel, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

        // Draw cube


         glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 48);

      //  glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 36);

        // Swap buffers
        window.display();

    }
    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
}
```

The transformed coordinates returned by the transform feed back are:

```
-2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
```

== what i got after the recommandations you gave me 
i did your recommendation, this is what i got when i'm facing the red face of the cube

lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 9.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)
);

```css
NDC before division by w
-2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 10.6111 10.5
-2.71599 -2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 6.94444 7.5
-2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5


NDC after division by w (all component are divied by w)
-0.362132 -0.321895 0.925926 1
0.362132 -0.321895 0.925926 1
0.362132 0.321895 0.925926 1
-0.362132 0.321895 0.925926 1
0.258666 -0.229925 1.01058 1
0.258666 0.229925 1.01058 1
0.362132 0.321895 0.925926 1
0.362132 -0.321895 0.925926 1
-0.258666 -0.229925 1.01058 1
-0.258666 0.229925 1.01058 1
0.258666 0.229925 1.01058 1
0.258666 -0.229925 1.01058 1
-0.258666 -0.229925 1.01058 1
-0.362132 -0.321895 0.925926 1
-0.362132 0.321895 0.925926 1
-0.258666 0.229925 1.01058 1

window x and windoy coords
255.147 135.621
544.853 135.621
544.853 264.379
255.147 264.379
503.466 154.015
503.466 245.985
544.853 264.379
544.853 135.621
296.534 154.015
296.534 245.985
503.466 245.985
503.466 154.015
296.534 154.015
255.147 135.621
255.147 264.379
296.534 245.985

z depth buffer
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1

WindowZ  transformed into [-1 1]
0.962963
0.962963
0.962963
0.962963
1.00529
1.00529
0.962963
0.962963
1.00529
1.00529
1.00529
1.00529
1.00529
0.962963
0.962963
1.00529
```

I don't know why the values of the Z buffet are all equal to 1 ?

The result semms good, because the visible vertices are those having their "WindowZ transformed coordinates into [-1 1]" < Z depth buffer.

When i change the position of the camera with a lookat(..), the values of "WindowZ transformed coordinates into [-1 1]" become all < 1 despite the vertices are visible ! ?

Comment: i added "Hi everybody" in my msg, but i doesn't appear!

Comment: We don't really like greetings and signatures here, they often get edited out eventually anyway.

Comment: Can you add the code you use to read the depth buffer to your question? I can tell you right away that all of your vertices are very close to the far clipping plane (some of them are even beyond it). ***All*** of your vertices are very close to the far clip plane, you should move the near clipping plane farther out in this case to enhance depth buffer precision.

Comment: for reading the depth buffer, i used  : 
float x; ReadPixels(windowX ,windowY, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &x);  // I put 1, 1 in parameters because if a put 800,600 the program beug! i read on a discussion that they should be 1 ,1 if we want to read 1 pixel from the Z buffer. For the near and far planes i use the distances : proj = glm::perspective(45.0f, 800.0f / 600.0f, 1.0f, 10.0f);

Comment: I did the math to calculate your window-space Y coordinates and got something different. You have a window with dimensions 800x600, so that means the viewport height is 600. (-0.321895 * 0.5 + 0.5) * 600 = 203.432, not 135.621.

Comment: So my windowY coordinates are wrong ? now, i have to put near plane=10, farplane=30, and correct the window coordinates ?

Comment: You can probably leave the near plane and far plane the way they are,   maybe push the far plane out to 15 (since some of your vertices are past 10). But you do need to fix the window Y coordinate. If you do both of those things you should get values in the depth buffer that are not **1.0**.

Answer (score 0):

#### There is nothing technically wrong with this.

You have 4D coordinates here with a non-**1.0** value for the `w` component, that is a dead giveaway that the coordinates are not in NDC space. During the transformation from clip-space to NDC space, ***all*** components are divided by `w` and this means that an NDC vector will always have a `w` component of **1.0**.

What you have here are the clip-space vertex positions. Divide everything by `w` and everything except for a couple of vertices with Z values beyond the farplane will fit nicely into your [**-1**,**1**] viewing volume.

#### This vertex in particular is clipped by the far plane:

```
-2.71599 2.41421 10.6111 10.5
```

#### Because this is the vertex after division by w

```
-0.25866 0.22992 1.01058 1.0
```

Comment: There is one interesting exception I didn't think was relevant to the discussion in the answer. If a clip-space vertex has a `w` coordinate of **0.0** it will have a non-**1.0** NDC-space vertex, but of course since this results in points at +/- infinity those vertices are always clipped anyway.

Comment: Oké good. Now i'm trying to read from the ZBUFFER. I know that the function glReadPixels() can read from it. But it has 2 pramaters (x,y) and i have a  negative parameters. I seems a little be weird to read from the z buffer with x and y negatives. Did i miss something in my comprehension ?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do. If you are referring to the X and Y coordinates you got from transform feedback, I would suggest you transform them into NDC space and then follow the discussion I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789753/from-window-to-opengl-coordinate-system-intuitive-explanation/26790057#26790057). That explains how to map screen coordinates to NDC coordinates given the viewport (you want to go the other way, but that shouldn't be hard to figure out).

Comment: Yes i'm referring to the x and y i got from the transform feedback. I'm new to OpenGL and i don't really have the capacities to understand what is the difference between viewport and NDC... (i'm still reading tutorials). what are the formulas i have to compute to transform them into x and y and capture the Z coordinate from the z buffer. my aim is to compare the z coordinates from the z buffer with the z i got from the transform feedback. (i have to detect which vertex is visible to the camera, that's why i'm doing that)

Comment: Okay, so let me simplify this a bit for you. After division by W like I showed you, your coordinates are in NDC space. You want them in window-space (also known as screenspace) so that you can use them in a call to `glReadPixels (...)`. To do this, you need to know the x,y location of the viewport and its height and width. You should be able to use the following: `Window_x = (NDC_x * 0.5 + 0.5) * Viewport_width  + Viewport_x` and `Window_y = (NDC_y * 0.5 + 0.5) * Viewport_height + Viewport_y` Those Window_x,y coordinates are what you pass to `glReadPixels (...)`.

Comment: The value you get back from the depth buffer will be in the range [**0**,**1**], so you also need to compensate for this by multiplying the NDC_z value (whose range is [**-1**,**1**]) this way: `Depth = (NDC_z * 0.5 + 0.5)` Then you can compare that depth with the depth you read from the depth buffer.

Comment: okay, i see more clear now :D. So the NDC_x is x i got from the transform feedback. For the Viewport_height and viewport_width, i think that they are those i used to create the context (800 and 600)? For the viewport_x and viewport_y, i don't know what are these values ?

Comment: Yes, if you've never made a call to [`glViewport (...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374202(v=vs.85).aspx) then the viewport dimensions will be the width and height of your window and viewport_x and viewport_y will just be **0**. It is possible to move the viewport around, and that is why you have to deal with the x,y coordinates in addition to width and height.

Comment: Ok, i'll will do your recommendations and i'll go back to you. Thank you for your explanations

Comment: hi i did the recommendations you told me, please look at the first question of the topic where i post what i've got after implementing your ideas (because the website doesn't let me post my response here !)