# SDL2 render without pixel units

Tags: opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I came from OpenGL but it was a little bit to low level for me so now I wanted to work with plain SDL2 for a small tile based game.
I wanted to ask how I can draw pixel independent like in OpenGL?
What I mean is, that in OpenGL there was always the coordinate system: "left -1, right 1, top -1, bottom 1", and I could draw things with float's completely pixel independent.
But now in SDL2 I can only render in pixel units.
I don't like that, so I search a way, how I can get the usual OpenGL feeling.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: "Independent" coordinate systems really just map down to pixels, but feature rounding errors in the process. If you really need to use a [0.0f, 1.0f] coordinate system, write a helper class and convert to the nearest pixel (or nearest pow2 pixel) on your own. It will be much cleaner.

Comment: Your description of the OpenGL coordinate system (which is better known as Normalized Device Coordinates) is backwards by the way (**-1** is the bottom).

Answer (score 2):

#### Those are Normalized Device Coordinates.

They map the corners of your *viewport* to the range [**-1**,**1**]. All you need to do is implement your own mapping. I've explained this visually in [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789753/from-window-to-opengl-coordinate-system-intuitive-explanation/26790057#26790057).

#### You want to go the other direction though, so you would use:

Screen<sub>X</sub> = (NDC<sub>X</sub> * 0.5 + 0.5) * Viewport<sub>W</sub> + Viewport<sub>X</sub>

Screen<sub>Y</sub> = (NDC<sub>Y</sub> * 0.5 + 0.5) * Viewport<sub>H</sub> + Viewport<sub>Y</sub>