# How to determine the XYZ coords of a point on the back buffer

Tags: opengl, matrix, direct3d

If I pick a spot on my monitor in screen X/Y, how can I obtain the point in 3D space, based on my projection and view matrices?

For example, I want to put an object at depth and have it located at 10,10 in screen coords.  So when I update its world matrix it will render onscreen at 10,10.

I presume it's fairly straightforward given I have my camera matrices, but I'm not sure offhand how to 'reverse' the normal process.

DirectXTk XMMath would be best, but I can no doubt sort it out from any linear algebra system (OpenGL, D3DX, etc).

Comment: Your problem-statement is under-determined. There is a whole _line_ of points which will be mapped to a certain (x,y) screen space point. Classical "unprojecting" uses the depth value from the z buffer to completely inverse the process. YOu might of course jsut assume some z value if you don't care.

Comment: Yes, I'm happy to assume the Z is equal to the back buifer.  That's what I meant by "object at depth", though that's not terribly clear.

Comment: @Dave read the depth buffer back at that point, it'll be in the range **[0.0, 1.0]** and you'll have to undo depth range and perspective division. That's probably the only thing that's not entirely straight-forward. But I think any discussion of "unprojection" is likely to cover this. You need everything in NDC-space before you can unproject, so that involves your viewport / depth range in addition to matrices.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted what "on the back buffer" means. Do you mean on the far clipping plane? I thought you wanted the depth of an object that was rendered already.

Comment: What I'm actually trying to do is find a random point on the back clipping plane where I can start an object that then drifts straight towards the camera along its projection line.  So I want to keep picking points in deep space that are still within my view (no point creating ones outside in my case) and starting alien ships (or whatever) at that point.

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm actually trying to do is find a random point on the back clipping plane where I can start an object that then drifts straight towards the camera along its projection line. So I want to keep picking points in deep space that are still within my view (no point creating ones outside in my case) and starting alien ships (or whatever) at that point.

As discussed in my comments, you need four things to do this generally.

1. ModelView (GL) or View (D3D / general) matrix
2. Projection matrix
3. Viewport
4. Depth Range (let us assume default, **[0, 1]**)

What you are trying to do is locate in world-space a point that lies on the far clipping plane at a specific x,y coordinate in window-space. The point you are looking for is `<x,y,1>` *(**z=1** corresponds to the far plane in window-space)*.

Given this point, you need to transform back to NDC-space

- The specifics are actually API-dependent since D3D's definition of NDC is different from OpenGL's -- *they do not agree on the range of Z (D3D = **[0, 1]**, GL = **[-1, 1]**)*.

Once in NDC-space, you can apply the inverse Projection matrix to transform back to view-space.

- *These are homogeneous coordinates and division by W is necessary.*

From view-space, apply the inverse View matrix to arrive at a point in world-space that satisfies your criteria.

---

Most math libraries have a function called `UnProject (...)` that will do all of this for you. I would suggest using that because you tagged this question D3D and OpenGL and the specifics of some of these transformations is different depending on API.

You are better off knowing how they work, even if you never implement them yourself. I think the key thing you were missing was the viewport, I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789753/from-window-to-opengl-coordinate-system-intuitive-explanation/26790057#26790057) that explains this step visually.